# Node.js CORS resulting in 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, http, cors, fetch

Our website uses the HTML5 fetch API to make a call to our backend NodeJS service for certain actions. Our backend resides on a different domain to main website, so we have CORS enabled on the Node app. This works for 99% of our clients.

However, one client has been having issues. They are trying to access our website from their workplace (maybe their workplace network has higher security settings..?) and they're receiving the following error:

> api.our-node-backend.com/blah Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) book:1 Fetch API cannot
>   load https://api.our-node-backend.com/blah. Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://www.our-frontend-website.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

Our Node app is currently configured as follows:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});
// respond to options pre-flight
app.options('*', function(req, res) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Is there something wrong with this configuration? Other examples on stack overflow have Access-Control-Allow-Headers set to "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" instead of just "Content-Type". What difference does that make?

Comment: Take a look at your browsers' developer tools network tab and check if the header is present.

Comment: You might try to include `OPTIONS` as allowed-method, since the error error is on preflight. However it's odd that only one client has this happening. Are they perhaps using an old / rare browser? Is there any polyfills you use for fetch to support older browsers?